# How does Firebird client/server compare to DB2 Express C

Tags: database, db2, firebird

I was about to use Firebird for a project, when someone told that DB2 Express C is also free, and with plethora of tools, and is also mature.

I read Firebird is also good for use as enterprise client/server database.

Then how does it compare to DB2 Express C?

Could the experienced ones shed some light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with Firebird Facts http://www.firebirdsql.org/guide/Firebird_Factsheet.pdf There are no real limits for Firebird and another good part that it comes with a real open source license so you can modify and deploy it how you want with your delphi/c#/php... application , You can use it as small embedded dll or you can use it as multithreaded server with many benefits when you have more cores in the deskopt/server machine 
So compared with db2 express is no brainer that we support more than 
 Processor: with only 2 cores
And more than 2G of ram (that is the very small in my opinion)

The true freedom comes that you can send the patches/enhancements back if you find some bugs (yes all database engines have them) and you can join Firebird community and be an open source developer or a community member if you want.

Answer (score 3):

I will start by saying that by being a [DB2 guy](http://FreeDB2.com)  I am naturally biased towards DB2. I also want to say that while I do have some hands on experience with Firebird, this was years ago before it was even called Firebird. So, I don't think I should be relied on for any direct comparisons of the two.

There are many DBMS out there and sometimes several may be a good choice for the same project. DB2 Express-C is a great choice if you are looking for a database that:

- is FREE but you don't particularly care about having access to its source code because it is not open source. However, it is free (as in beer) for development, production and even redistribution as part of a commercial application. In this way it is *"more free"* than some of the open source DBMS (e.g. MySQL requires that you sign and pay for an OEM agreement) if you wan tot redistribute
- Your customers will easily accept because it is part of their corporate standard. We work with many ISVs who see DB2 Express-C as a way in to larger corporate accounts. In many cases these accounts will not accept some of the open source databases for a variety of reasons
- You care about XML. DB2 Express-C has a hybrid database engine that provides very sophisticated functionality for both relationally structured data as well as XML data. It also had built-in capabilities for directly interacting with web services
- You care about using leading edge trusted technology that is used to process billions of critical business transactions every day by airlines, retailers, banks etc.
- You need to have DBMS technology that you will not hit a wall and will not embarrass you in the process no matter how big your customer gets

Basically, DB2 Express-C is real DB2 (exactly the same code). It is the same DB2 that is used by worlds largest companies but you get it for free. If this appeals to you, than by all means go with [DB2 Express-C](http://www.ibm.com/db2/express/download.html?S_TACT=LKFREE000&S_CMP=ECDDWW01) and you will not be disappointed. If you do decide to give DB2 Express-C a try (and even if you don't), I recommend you also get a [free book on DB2 Express-C](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/DB2/FREE+Book-+Getting+Started+with+DB2+Express-C?S_TACT=LKFREE000&S_CMP=ECDDWW01).

Answer (score 1):

Firebird has improved a lot since then. Actually there are very good drivers, components and libraries that allow a decent WAN connection using Firebird. We have established a connection between Buenos Aires (Argentina) and San José (Costa Rica) and it can retrieve 1000 records in two seconds. Not bad for two domestic connections.

Answer (score 0):

The only goal of DB2 Express C is to use DB2 after.

There is some limitation [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express/about.html?S_TACT=index&S_CMP=expcsite)

- Processor: 2 cores
- Memory: 2 GB

Althought DB2 is not open source.

I think Firebird user are not the same as DB2 Express user.

Comment: I disagree. The goal of DB2 Express-C is to offer a free version to those who don't have heavy deployment needs. Commercial support is available as well, if you are looking for the "economical" motivation for IBM. (Disclaimer: I'm part of the DB2 team)

Comment: The goal of the FREE DB2 Express-C is to provide DB2 technology to those customers and partners who need real enterprise class database but could not afford to purchase technology like that. In the past, these customers would have gone with other free alternatives i.e. this is not a customer set where IBM would have money anyway. We still like to have people like that to have the benefit of the DB2 technology. Some of these will become very successful and will need IBM support which we do offer just like MySQL and IBPhoenix does for Firebird.

Comment: Nice to see DB2 Express-C Team here :)
So what will you do if your customer need more than 2GB : you will give him for free if he don't need support ? :P

Comment: In response to Hugues Van Landeghem, the 2GB memory limit is fairly generous, considering that the limit only applies to memory used by the DB2 engine and not the total RAM available to the operating system. As with all databases, DB2 aggressively caches "hot" data and index pages in RAM, and is just as aggressive at flushing cached pages that haven't been accessed for a while. At any one moment, there is far less than 2GB of hot data in the cache, so the average DB2 Express-C database is far more likely to encounter a CPU bottleneck before it hits the 2GB limit of allocated RAM.

Answer (score 0):

One of the thing to consider with Firebird is its poor WAN performance.  If you're going to be accessing a database on a remote PC or even setup data replication over a WAN network, then Firebird may not be for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to know the purpose of using a database. For small databases, with no support and free redistribution, you can choose not only Firebird, but also MySQL or Postgresql. In the same way, you can choose one of the popular noSQL databases. It is a good thing to know why are you using a database, and see how is going to be the future of your data.

There are many open source database, but I have a question: when are you going to modify the code of a database? I think if you are a application developer, you only trust in your database, you should not care if a database is making the joins correctly, you only trust that they are correct.

The question you should care is: how you data is going to scale? and does you database will be prepared to manage that data? With a real database manager you do not care about that, because the vendors offer a bunch of options to increase the capabilities of the database.

Also, you have to take into account the administration. DB2 is self monitored and it takes important decisions for you (change memory heaps, tablespaces, backups, stats, reorgs). I do not know, but many of the open sources options do not have that features automatized, and you have to take these decision, even if they affect performance. This could be a big problem if you have an issue with the database, and you do not find the solution for your problem. If your data is not important, that is OK, an open source unsupported database could work for you, but who does not care about data?

To choose a database is necessary to make a complete analysis of the market. A place to start could be Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems

Many of the closed source database, now offer a free edition (Oracle, MS SQL server, IBM DB2), however, in the case of the first two, the free edition is an old version, not the latest. Instead, IBM releases the last fixpack in this edition, that allows you to use the latest features DB2 offers. The db2 free edition has limits, but they are big enough to start, it is just that IBM does not want customers using big databases without support. Take a look of the price of support of the open source database, and in the long term you will see that is more attractive a closed source database with support.

Do not get confused about the possibility of see the source of the database, it is not important. The important is your data.